# Parsing JsonObject into kotlin Data class

Tags: android, json, kotlin, android-volley, data-class

I am fairly new to `Kotlin` and I am trying to parse the `JsonObject` that I get from my `HTTPRequest` into `data class`. But I cannot get the `Instance` from the `data` class.

```
val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
    Response.Listener { response ->
        val text = "Response: %s".format(response.toString())
        print(text)
    },
    Response.ErrorListener { error ->
        // TODO: Handle error
    }

)

@Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
@Override
fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
    var params = HashMap<String, String>()
    if (params == null) params = HashMap()
    val basicAuth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString("username:password".toByteArray(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
    params["Authorization"] = basicAuth
    //..add other headers
    return params
}

TempJsonObject.instance?.addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest)
```

**Data Class**

```
data class TempJsonObject(
    val content: List<Content>) {
data class Content(
        val kioskId: Int,
        val location: Location,
        val stats: Stats,
        val settings: Settings,
        val modules: String,
        val visibility: String
) {
    data class Stats(
            val allLockers: Int,
            val emptyLockers: Int,
            val malfunctionLockers: Int,
            val forCustomer: Int,
            val forCourier: Int,
            val bySize: BySize,
            val incoming: Any
    ) {
        data class BySize(
                val XXSMALL: Xxsmall,
                val XSMALL: Xsmall,
                val SMALL: Small,
                val MEDIUM: Medium,
                val LARGE: Large,
                val XLARGE: Xlarge
        ) {
            data class Xxsmall(
                    val empty: Int,
                    val hasContent: Int
            )
        ...
```

Is the way I am trying to do it the right approach and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Alright, sorry, will not use it anymore.

Comment: Can you paste a piece where you actually parse the JSON? I don't quite get the line with `instance?`. Please also write what happens when you run your code.

Comment: @PiotrK sorry for the long answer, had no access to the computer on weekdays, but updated the code. Also I cannot run the code since I get the following error: "Unresolved reference:instance"

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `instance?.addToRequestQueue`, it's really puzzling me. I don't know any Kotlin API like this for parsing JSONs. I thought that you use some library that adds such API, but you also wrote in the comment that the code doesn't compile because of lack of `instance` field. It looks like it exposes some singleton instance of the data class. Could you point me to any working example using such API, or any other source that you used?

If the above turns out to be incorrect, I would just use some Kotlin or Java library to parse the JSON into an **instance** of the data class. One option is the Kotlin library Klaxon: https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon. Quoting one of its examples that should fit your use case:

```
val result = Klaxon().parse<Person>(""" { "name": "John Smith", } """)

assert(result?.name == "John Smith")
assert(result.age == 23)
```

Comment: I am using `Volley` and an example can be found here `https://android--code.blogspot.com/2019/02/android-kotlin-volley-post-request-with.html`. In the end I gave up on using `Volley` and went with this line `return Gson().fromJson(JSONObject(response).toString(), TempJsonObject::class.java)` while using `OkHttp`